# How to dynamically add template with set of configs in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs2, vue.js

I use VueJs to make dynamic grid structure.

This Grip need some set of configs like,

```
   var sets = {
          "nb": 3,
          "column": 4,
          "list": false,
          "action_text": "Action 0",
       };

    var templates = [{
          "nb": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "list": false,
          "action_text": "Action 0",
       },
        {
          "nb": 1,
          "column": 2,
          "list": false,
          "action_text": "Action 0",
       }];
```

My VueJs for Template is,

```
  Vue.component('campaign_segment', {
    template: '#segment_body',
    props: ['t_nb', 't_column', 't_show_list', 't_action_text'],

    data: function () {
        return {
            n: templates,
            nb: this.t_nb,
            column: this.t_column
            } 
        }
    }
```

My Template Skeleton is,

```
  <div v-for="(te,index) in templates" class="row">
    <campaign_segment :t_nb="te.nb" :t_column=te.column :t_show_list="te.list"
                      :t_action_text="te.action_text">
    </campaign_segment>
  </div>
```

Here, if i try like this,

```
  var k = 3;

  <div v-for="n in k class="row">
    <p> {{ n }} </p>
  </div>
```

I get output as,

```
     1
     2
```

If i increase the value of "k", its dynamically reflects.

In my case, i need to pass set of config to existing list.

**OnLoad**, the defined list works fine, but if i try to inject(push or append), then it won't work.

I try,

```
  templates[2] = dummy_segment;
  console.log(templates);
```

Output is,

```
  Object { 0: Getter, 1: Getter, 2: Object, 1 more… }
```

Here, newly added object is totally different from existing.

Both are objects.

I need pure append of objects.

After processing template, the existing sets are shown as "Getter" Why ?

What's wrong with my code ?

Is it possible (by Only add Set of Config) ?

Comment: To answer your getter question, I believe this is how reactivity is accomplished, each object is created as a class that has methods to monitor changes. You can probably just do an object.assign if you don't want to see the getter, setters but you really don't need to. Additionally there is a log method documented in the API docs that shows the objects without the getter/setters I believe it's .$log

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'll check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you `templates` variable is not part of vue instance, changing this will not have any effect on vue code, it will not be reactive.

[Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection) are the mutation methods on array, which will trigger change detection for vue instance variables.

> - push()

- pop()
- shift()
- unshift()
- splice()
- sort()
- reverse()

Comment: If i use ".push()", then i get response as, 'push() is not a function'.
Also my issue is appending a new object as a element in an existing object. But there, dynamic link won't work. So i try to make virtual push. Finally i got a solution, Issue on binding object. Initially, i use core object for loop. After i use object via Vue Variable. Now its works fine. Thanks @Saurabh.